# No access in the bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to the bash script. I want to carry out the simulation using bash and I want to make it open the fortran program file.

While I am writing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "****************************"
./box1.f95 < indata1 >screen_output1
```

It says it does not have an acces to the `box1.f95` file. Why is it working like that even though I have this file in the same directory where the bash script is?

Comment: Could you show the error text?

Comment: ./script: line 4: ./box1.f95: No access.

Comment: are you sure that `box1.f95` is not a source file?

Comment: Yes! I have already realized that I need to execute the source file and conesuctively run it. Thank You!

Comment: Isn't `Fortran` a compiled language? You must compile and run the binary. You can't execute the source file. And don't speak like that, please, it's a volunteers' site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a file permission problem, specifically the **execute** permission is not set on the file. Try running the following command:

```
chmod a+x box1.f95
```

This will give all users privileges to execute the file. Please note that this assumes that the file is actually executable in one way or another! That means that it has to be a binary executable, or be an interpretable file, starting with a line like **#!/path/to/interpreter**.

If the file is containing fortran source code, you need to compile it to an executable program, or install a program like [binfmtf95-interpreter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/binfmtf95-interpreter.1.html).